# R: merge two dataframes based on substring

Tags: r, merge, substring

I have two dataframes. The `df1` one looks like:

```
           Day     Element    Incident
1   2020-04-06     3101       Check incident by SOILING
2   2020-04-02     3102       Check alarm 5662
3   2020-05-21     3101       Check energy loss by METEO ERROR
4   2020-04-02     3202       Check ACDC grid
```

The other one, `df2`, looks like this:

```
         Day     Element  Incident       Energy_loss
1 2020-04-06     3101     SOILING        0.05
2 2020-04-14     3101     SOILING        0.01
3 2020-05-21     3101     METEO ERROR    0.11
4 2020-06-15     3102     METEO ERROR    0.03
```

I would like to merge them based on the columns `Day`, `Element` and `Incident`, so I need to find when the column `Incident` in `df1` contains the column `Incident` of `df2`. The rows where `df1` doesn't have a match with `df2` can be left with a `Nan` in the `Energy loss` column.

I've tried with the usual merge, but as one of the conditions of the `merge` is by a substring, it's not working properly.

The output I expect is:

```
           Day     Element    Incident                          Energy loss
1   2020-04-06     3101       Check incident by SOILING                0.05
2   2020-04-02     3102       Check alarm 5662                          Nan
3   2020-05-21     3101       Check energy loss by METEO ERROR         0.11
4   2020-04-02     3202       Check ACDC grid                           Nan
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use `regex_left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
library(fuzzyjoin)
regex_left_join(df1, df2, by = c('Day', 'Element', 'Incident')) %>% 
    select(Day = Day.x, Element = Element.x, Incident = Incident.x, Energy_loss)
```

-output

```
#       Day Element                         Incident Energy_loss
#1 2020-04-06    3101        Check incident by SOILING        0.05
#2 2020-04-02    3102                 Check alarm 5662          NA
#3 2020-05-21    3101 Check energy loss by METEO ERROR        0.11
#4 2020-04-02    3202                  Check ACDC grid          NA
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Day = c("2020-04-06", "2020-04-02", "2020-05-21", 
"2020-04-02"), Element = c(3101L, 3102L, 3101L, 3202L), 
Incident = c("Check incident by SOILING", 
"Check alarm 5662", "Check energy loss by METEO ERROR", "Check ACDC grid"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4"))

df2 <- structure(list(Day = c("2020-04-06", "2020-04-14", "2020-05-21", 
"2020-06-15"), Element = c(3101L, 3101L, 3101L, 3102L), Incident = c("SOILING", 
"SOILING", "METEO ERROR", "METEO ERROR"), Energy_loss = c(0.05, 
0.01, 0.11, 0.03)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```